# Pattern matching using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a stream from which I read a string that looks like the following:

```
event.tag.report tag_id=0xABCD0029605, type=ISOB_80K, antenna=1, frequency=918250, rssi=-471, tx_power=330, time=2017-12-18T19:44:07.198
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am trying to use Regex to just get the highlighted part (underlined by `^^^^`) for every string that I read. My pattern for the Regex is as follows:

```
.*\\s(tag_id=)(.{38})(\\,\\s)(.*)$
```

However, this does not work for `tag_id`s which are longer than or shorter than 38 digits.

Can someone help me with a string pattern that will help me just get the highlighted area in the string independent of its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as though you want all hexidecimal characters:

```
"tag_id=(0x[A-F0-9]+)"
```

So

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("tag_id=(0x[A-F0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("event.tag.report tag_id=0x313532384D3135374333343435393031, type=ISOC");
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

returns:

```
0x313532384D3135374333343435393031
```

Comment: Hey, this seems to work only partially I am unable to get the entire string before the ,.  if my String has tag_id=0x313532384D3135374333343435393031 then it only outputs tag_id=0x313532384D313537.

Comment: @SagarNair Not for me. I added my test code and it works fine. Are you sure you don't have a hidden character after the 7?

Comment: can you please try this string `event.tag.report tag_id=0x3504B40180019F112A05F6EB, type=ISOC, antenna=2, frequency=918250, rssi=-638, tx_power=330, time=2017-12-18T20:17:02.865`. I am sorry I know I can too but its not working for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @SagarNair yes that works fine. Altered the code to demonstrate. Note that I changed `matches` for `find` because the pattern matches a part of the input, not the entire input.